# JAVA project with SSO using SAML 2.0 with ADFS and AD

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs

I require references or guides for creating working java project with SSO using SAML 2.0 with ADFS and AD.

I tried with link (https://www.journaldev.com/21773/azure-ad-sso-java-adfs-sso) but not able to complete (ADFS Configuration for Single Sign-On SSO) part.

Please guide.

Comment: You need to be more specific. What problems do you have with implementing tutorial you linked? Show some code. Otherwise voting to close as "too broad".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ADFS, you need the [ADAL Java library](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java).

Note that most of the documentation is for Azure AD but the principles are the same.

There are some examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/ad-fs-development).

In particular, [this sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/enabling-oauth-confidential-clients-with-ad-fs) shows the changes required to work with ADFS.